# login event handling in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i am trying to hook to the login even in my L5 app to set last login time and IP address. i can make it work with the following:

```
Event::listen('auth.login', function($event)
{
    Auth::user()->last_login = new DateTime;
    Auth::user()->last_login_ip = Request::getClientIp();
    Auth::user()->save();
});
```

however, i am wondering what the best way to do this in L5 is with the event handler object. i tried creating an event handler and adding auth.login as an array key in the events service provider, however that didnt work. im not sure if that is possible or not with the auth.login event. if it isnt, where is the most appropriate place to put the above code. for testing, i put it in my routes.php file, but i know that isnt where it should be.

Comment: Please next time do work with manual :) provided answer by @kstev is best shot you got. I know manual is not a walkthru but it is really usefull, http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/events

Comment: @Kyslik i did look at the manual, i just wasn't sure how to hook to the existing event that laravel fires. the below answer by kstev is very thorough, yet im still confused as to where they add the even to be fired. when i was tracing the auth controller and trying to find where login is successful, i couldnt.....

Comment: You have to do it yourself, I think events are fired only on eloquent insert, update, delete I can not find the complete list :/ only for L3. See this tutorial https://laracasts.com/lessons/laravel-5-events and **discussion!**

Comment: @Kyslik the string based event in my above code works using 'auth.login' but i wasn't able to register it in the event service provider and thats where all the confusion started. i was trying to do 'auth.login' => [
        UpdateUserMetaData::class
    ]

Comment: I finally understood what you were asking the whole time ;) see my answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**EDIT: this only works in 5.0.* and 5.1.*.**

**For the 5.2.* solution see JuLiAnc response below.**

after working with both proposed answers, and some more research i finally figured out how to do this the way i was trying at first.

i ran the following artisan command

```
$ php artisan handler:event AuthLoginEventHandler
```

Then i altered the generated class removing the import of the Event class and and imported the user model. I also passed `User $user` and `$remember` to the handle method since when the auth.login event is fired, thats what is passed.

```
<?php namespace App\Handlers\Events;

use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeQueued;
use App\User;

class AuthLoginEventHandler {

    /**
     * Create the event handler.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  User $user
     * @param  $remember
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(User $user, $remember)
    {
        dd("login fired and handled by class with User instance and remember variable");
    }

}
```

now i opened EventServiceProvided.php and modified the `$listen` array as follows:

```
protected $listen = [
    'auth.login' => [
        'App\Handlers\Events\AuthLoginEventHandler',
    ],
];
```

i realized if this doesn't work at first, you may need to

```
$ php artisan clear-compiled
```

There we go! we can now respond to the user logging in via the auth.login event using an event handler class!

Answer (score 27):

In laravel 5.2; auth.login won't work... the following will have to be used:

```
protected $listen = [
    'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Attempting' => [
        'App\Listeners\LogAuthenticationAttempt',
    ],

    'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login' => [
        'App\Listeners\LogSuccessfulLogin',
    ],

    'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Logout' => [
        'App\Listeners\LogSuccessfulLogout',
    ],

    'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Lockout' => [
        'App\Listeners\LogLockout',
    ],
];
```

As stated in the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#events)

Comment: thanks for this! I haven't updated to 5.2 yet on the application that i used the above code, but will make sure to update my listeners!

Comment: This is the best answer!

Answer (score 15):

Be careful about asking *what the best way to do X* is, because Laravel, in particular, provides many ways of accomplishing the same task -- some are better than others in certain situations.

Taking a look at the [Laravel documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/master/events#basic-usage), personally I would go with the "Basic Usage" as it seems to match the use case you have stated.

If we run the following Artisan command we can generate a template for the UserLoggedIn event.

```
$ php artisan make:event UserLoggedIn
```

(note the past tense, because events happen, and *then* the subscribers are notified of the event having taken place)

(note 2: the `app` string in namespaces is what Laravel uses out of the box, it is likely different for you if you have executed the `php artisan app:name` command)

The following class is generated for us:

```
<?php namespace app\Events;

use app\Events\Event;

use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class UserLoggedIn extends Event {

    use SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

}
```

If we add a `userId` parameter to the constructor, then the event doesn't need to know about the Auth Facade/Guard Contract. This means our `UserLoggedIn` event code is not tightly coupled to Eloquent or which ever authentication framework you decide to utilize in your app. Anyways, let's add that `userId` parameter.

```
<?php namespace app\Events;

use app\Events\Event;
use app\User;

use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class UserLoggedIn extends Event {

    use SerializesModels;

    public $userId;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @param int userId the primary key of the user who was just authenticated.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($userId)
    {
        $this->userId = $userId;
    }

}
```

Now you're probably wondering, well that's great and all, but how to we act on this event? Great question! We need to create an event handler to handle when this event is fired. Let's do that now using Artisan:

```
$ php artisan handler:event UpdateUserMetaData --event=UserLoggedIn
```

We name our new event handler `UpdateUserMetaData` and tell Artisan that the event we want to handle is the `UserLoggedIn` event.

Now we have some code that looks like this inside of `app/Handlers/Events/UpdateUserMetaData.php`:

```
<?php namespace app\Handlers\Events;

use app\Events\UserLoggedIn;

use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeQueued;

class UpdateUserMetaData {

    /**
     * Create the event handler.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  UserLoggedIn  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(UserLoggedIn $event)
    {
        //
    }

}
```

We can update the handle method to be able to handle this event like you specified above quite easily:

```
<?php namespace app\Handlers\Events;

use app\Events\UserLoggedIn;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UpdateUserMetaData {

    protected $request;

    /**
     * Create the event handler.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     */
    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  UserLoggedIn  $event
     */
    public function handle(UserLoggedIn $event)
    {
        $user = User::find($event->userId); // find the user associated with this event
        $user->last_login = new DateTime;
        $user->last_login_ip = $this->request->getClientIp();
        $user->save();
    }

}
```

As a side note, if you're not familiar with [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon#carbon), you might want to look into using it so you can take advantage of its fantastic API like you can with Eloquent's `created_at` and `updated_at` timestamp fields on most models. Here's a link for how to tell Eloquent which fields should be used with Carbon: http://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#date-mutators.

There are two final steps we have to perform before this code will work in your Laravel app.

1. We need to map the event to the event handler in the `EventServiceProvider` class under the `app/Providers` directory.
2. We need to fire the event after login.

To complete the first step, we just need to add our event classes to the `$listeners` property in `app/Providers/EventServiceProvder.php` like so:

```
    UserLoggedIn::class => [
        UpdateUserMetaData::class
    ]
```

The above will work provided you import the classes inside the `EventServiceProvider` class, and you are using PHP 5.5. If you're using a lower PHP version, you'll need to provide the full path to each class as a string like this: `'app/Events/UserLoggedIn'` and `'app/Handlers/Events/UpdateUserMetaData'`.

The `$listeners` array maps events to their respective handlers.

Okay, now for the final step! In your code base, find the place where the user is authenticated and add the following:

```
event(new \app\Events\UserLoggedIn(Auth::user()->id));
```

And we're done! I tested this code as I wrote this answer, feel free to ask follow up questions if you have any.

Comment: Haha, I was crafting same "long butt (as*)" answer. I came to conclusion that `$ php artisan event:generate` does **not** generate both handler and event probably a bug?

Comment: Heh, I haven't tried the `event:generate` command, I just prefer to make it all a bit explicit rather than letting Artisan do all the work for me, just to make sure everything happens how I expect. I actually opened this question again in a new tab about 75% of the way through to make sure no one else had posted an answer haha. I'd love to see alternative approaches if you have one!

Comment: Nah, pretty much the same, but I send Eloquent model instead. I know you are making good point about leaving eloquent at the door but its one big bubble please read this: https://laracasts.com/forum/?p=718-repository-pattern-and-eloquent-models/p1#p3546 thats why I do not decouple like crazy. And one more point, by sending user_id instead model you need to run one more query and I am sure that you run it already just look at debugbar (package). I use Eloquent  ORM so I use it fulltime. I may abstract some stuff in repository but not everything.

Comment: @Kyslik I can definitely see where you're coming from. I will update my answer in a few minutes to reflect that. This is why I love the StackExchange network :)

Comment: Here is the bug I was talking about, https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/7264 And do use artisan, it helps a lot! I mean I try to utilize everything Laravel offers. Laravel is huge community I do not understand that there is laracast forum, stackoverflow tags and laravel.io so many sites to check... I am frustrated by that.

Comment: @kstev - in a fresh L5 install, where did u place the event(new \app....); fire code? thats where i was getting stuck, hence trying to hook into the string based event "auth.login" as described in the doc for authentication

Comment: Could you explain why you would use an Event Handler versus a Listener? What exactly is the difference?

Comment: I thought the `php artisan event:generate` is will generate class any events or handlers that are listed in your EventServiceProvider

Answer (score 12):

For 5.2 something like this

in Listeners:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login;

class UpdateLastLoginWithIp
{
    public function handle(Login $event)
    {
        $event->user->last_login_at = Carbon::now();
        $event->user->last_login_ip = Request::getClientIp()
        $event->user->save();
    }
}
```

In EventServiceProvider.php :

```
protected $listen = [
        'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login' => [
            'City\Listeners\UpdateLastLoginWithIp',
        ],
    ];
```

Comment: ReflectionException in Container.php line 734:
Class City\Listeners\UpdateLastLoginWithIp does not exist

Comment: Thanks it works! But, how can I get current `Request` inside `handle` function?

Answer (score 7):

Usually you can achieve by doing like this step by step for User Login Logs

first, you should have Auth Scaffolding

1. use this as event,

   - **'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login'** for Login Event
   - **'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Logout'** for Logout Event

located the login and logout event at :

**vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Events**

EventServiceProvider.php

```
protected $listen = [

    'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login' => [
        'App\Listeners\LoginLogs',
    ],

    'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Logout' => [
        'App\Listeners\LogoutLogs',
    ],

];


public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

}
```

2. then after you get done for EventServiceProvider, do this next step

   - type this artisan command **php artisan event:generate**
   - look for folder **Listener** inside App folder, check if contains php files both **LoginLogs** and **LogoutLogs**
3. create your **migration** and **model**

**command:** php artisan make:migration create_UserLoginHistory

**Migration File**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('tbl_user_login_history', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->datetime('login_at')->nullable();
        $table->datetime('logout_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('login_ip')->nullable();
        $table->string('role');
        $table->string('session_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}


public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('tbl_user_login_history');
}
```

then your **Model** : **UserLoginHistory**

```
public $timestamps = false;

protected $table = 'tbl_user_login_history';

protected $fillable = ['user_id','login_at','logout_at','login_ip','role','session_id'];

public function setLogOutLog(){

    $this->where('session_id',request()->session()->getId())->update([
        'logout_at' =>Carbon::now(),
        ]);

}

public function setLogInLog(){
    $this->insert(
        ['user_id' => Auth::user()->id,'login_at' =>Carbon::now(),
        'login_ip'=>request()->getClientIp(),'role' =>Auth::user()->role,
        'session_id'=>request()->session()->getId()
        ]);  
}
```

4.after the migration and model creation procedure, let's assume that you have already in roles in users table

5. the listener part

**Listener** : **LoginLogs** Class

```
use App\UserLoginHistory;


private $UserLoginHistory; 

public function __construct(UserLoginHistory $UserLoginHistory)
{
  // the initialization of  private $UserLoginHistory; 

    $this->UserLoginHistory = $UserLoginHistory;
}


public function handle(Login $event)
{   
     // from model UserLoginHistory

     $this->UserLoginHistory->setLogInLog();
}
```

**Listener** : **LogoutLogs**  Class

```
private $UserLogoutHistory; 

public function __construct(UserLoginHistory $UserLoginHistory)
{
    // the initialization of  private $UserLogoutHistory; 

    $this->UserLogoutHistory = $UserLoginHistory;
}


public function handle(Logout $event)
{
    // from model UserLoginHistory
     $this->UserLogoutHistory->setLogOutLog();
}
```

after you do this all steps , try to login with Auth

Comment: $this->where('session_id',request()->session()->getId())->update([
        'logout_at' =>Carbon::now(),
        ]);     that's not working, could you please tell me why?

Comment: @HimaHima, did u find a solution? i also want to track user login and logout

Comment: tracking both login and logout, the best way to do is make a separate table as audit trail. Place the logic inside the login method that would save about the (id, datetime, type)

Table: audit_log  -> login logout tracing 
Columns:  id, datetime, and type

Answer (score 4):

here is my approach:
 I have done for making an event handler when user logged in using:

- Laravel 5.8

1) Run the following artian command
    `php artisan make:listener Auth/UserLoggedIn --event='Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login'`* 
It will make a Listener: `UserLoggedIn` in folder `app\Listeners\Auth\`

2) Then you need to add this listener into your `EventServiceProvider`:**

```php
...
protected $listen = [
   ...
        'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login' => [
            'App\Listeners\Auth\UserLoggedIn',
        ],
    ];
```

Finaly you can do log when user logged in in `handle` function located at `UserLoggedIn` Listener:

```php
public function handle(Login $event)
    {
        //you have access to user object by using : $event->user
    }
```

- you can use all other Auth events, here is the possible events:

```
'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered', 
'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Attempting', 
'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Authenticated', 
'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login', 
'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Failed',
'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Logout',
'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Lockout',
```

**You can use all these events in your `EventServiceProvider`:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#events

Answer (score 2):

Open up EventServiceProvider.php and in boot method you can listen for `'auth.login'` event via callback.

```
public function boot(DispatcherContract $events)
{
    parent::boot($events);
    $events->listen('auth.login', function() 
    {
        dd('logged in event');
    });
}
```

You may want to create listener so you move callback function somewhere else. Do that following this http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/events#using-classes-as-listeners

Comment: Going to give this a try. It's really frustrating I can't find where that event is fired though. I try to follow the auth controllers traits and the implementation of guard, and it's no where to be found!

Comment: HA - i found it. its only referenced as a string in the Guard implementation. guess this is the best way for now! unless i subscribe to the event....too many options..

Answer (score 0):

just did it this way

```
    <?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\User;
use Auth;
use DB;


use Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher as DispatcherContract;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The event listener mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $listen = [

    ];

    /**
     * Register any other events for your application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher  $events
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot(DispatcherContract $events)
    {
        parent::boot($events);

        $events->listen('auth.login', function() 
        {

            DB::table('users')
                -> where('id', Auth::id())
                -> update(array(
                        'last_login'    => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
                    ));

        });

        //
    }
}
```