# Kodeine Role and Permission assignment for Laravel 5

Tags: authentication, laravel

I have used  [kodeine](https://github.com/kodeine/laravel-acl) for Laravel user roles and permissions.  No problem in installation and all the migrations.  The only thing that troubles me is where to make the role assignment :

`$user->assignRole($roleAdmin);`

I tried creating a `postLogin` inside the `AuthController` but I believe creating this function will override Laravel's built in auth.  I have no problem with the built in auth, my issue is finding the best place to assign the roles and permissions for the current logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by adding an event handler (or 'listener' in 5.1). When a user is authenticated, an `auth.login` event is fired. Add a listener for that event, either in `EventServiceProvider::boot()` or in a custom listener class.

see: [login event handling in laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28970105/login-event-handling-in-laravel-5)

Edit: if you want to only add permissions upon user creation instead of every login, the event you want is `App\User::created` instead, like so in `app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php`:

```
public function boot(DispatcherContract $events)
{
    parent::boot($events);

    // after a user is created, see if we can attach a school to them
    \App\User::created(function($user)
    {
        $user->assignRole('admin');
    });
}
```