# How to track number of logins for a single user in Laravel 5.0

Tags: php, laravel

I went thru the Laravel 5.0 Documentations and i saw that I have to use Event in order to track the auth.login service. I added these lines of code on my route.php but it does not seem working:

```
    Event::listen('auth.login', function($user)
    {
        $user->login_counter = 1; //just for testing
        $user->save();
        //$user->increment('login_counter');
    });
```

Anyone have any idea why this is not firing, or how do I know if this code is at least being executed. Where do I need to add these lines of code exactly so it always fires when a user gets logged in!

Comment: Maybe this question help you out
[login event handling in laravel 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28970105/login-event-handling-in-laravel-5)

Comment: @MasoudHaghbin I went thru all of that code, and make sure everything is same, but still not working...

Answer (score 0):

Add a new column `login_counter` to you `users` table and see if it works

**UPDATE**

```
Event::listen('auth.login', function($event)
{
    Auth::user()->login_counter = 1;  
    Auth::user()->save();
});
```

I believe you've registered your Event/Listner

Comment: I have already had this column into users table, yet didt work

Comment: Have you followed all the steps for registering, generating, defining Event Listener from [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/events). No that's not a good Idea to write code in `route.php`.It's better you leave it for defining `routes` only

Comment: I am using Laravel 5.0 , the link u sent me is for 5.2... also I noticed smthh that the code inside the stm is never being used, like the auth.login is not getting fired for some reason

Comment: You can choose the version there.

Comment: actually I was looking for something more specific, its too easy to find the laravel documentation and the topic for it