# Event not firing Laravel 5.0.*

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 5.0.* and followed the following answer: [login event handling in laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28970105/login-event-handling-in-laravel-5) but I am still not able to see the event firing.

Anyone could help me with this:

This is how my Event Handler Class looks like:

```
<?php namespace App\Handlers\Events;

use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeQueued;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class AuthLoginEventHandler {

    /**
     * Create the event handler.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  User $user
     * @param  $remember
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(User $user, $remember)
    {
        //
        $user->login_counter = 1;
        $user->save();
//        $user->increment('login_counter');

        Log::error('something wrong happened');
//        dd("login fired and handled by class with User instance and remember variable");
    }

}
```

And this is the EventServiceProvider:

```
<?php namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher as DispatcherContract;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    /**
     * The event handler mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $listen = [
        'auth.login' => [
            'App\Handlers\Events\AuthLoginEventHandler',
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * Register any other events for your application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher  $events
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot(DispatcherContract $events)
    {
        parent::boot($events);

        //
    }

}
```

Appreciate your help

Comment: Did you try doing exactly as the [docs show](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/events) to see if you could get that working first ?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy yes, I did exactly the same thing but still not working... I dont see any mistake on my code, nor something missing, I just dont understand why the auth.login not firing at all...

Comment: also tried Event::listen('auth.login', function($event)
{
    // Handle the event...
}); directly from boot() method, still no change, event not firing

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, finally it did worked when I did exactly the same as in doc, The event was firing when I called: $response = Event::fire(new PodcastWasPurchased()); within boot().... I dont understand why auth.login event is not firing...

Comment: so this is firing everytime I make a call, I would like to fire an event only when user gets logged in... Do you by any chance know any other alternative how to achieve this using Laravel 5.0.*??

Comment: just so u know, this thing also did not seem working when called within boot() :         Event::listen('App\Events\PodcastWasPurchased', function($event)
        {
            Log::info('event fired');
        });

Answer (score 0):

I use Laravel 5.2. I spent hours trying to figure out why my listener is not responding not knowing that I misspelled the event class name in the $listen array. Basically, if you fire your event like event(new SameEventClass(...)) make sure it is the same name you used in $listen => ['SameEventClass' => ['SameListener']]