# laravel : how to run class auto

Tags: php, api, laravel, laravel-5.1

I have an api class and i want that when the user logged in system this class should run auto and return true or false. i don't want to call this to every class.

i don't want this :

> $api = new Api();

what can i do for this or it could be that :

> $ret = Api::run(); // this will run auto when the user logged in but run only one time not run every redirect or refresh

and i want use it like this:

> return View('api.show')->withApi($ret);

Should this return a bool variable and use every class which i want to use it in?

//edited there

```
use App\Helpers\api\gg\gg as gg;
class HomeController extends Controller
{

private $ggr;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
    $this->ggr = (new gg)->ggReady;
}

public function index()
{
    return view('pages.home')
            ->withApis([
                'gg' => [
                    'text' => trans('common.api.gg')
                    , 'ready' => $this->ggr
                    , 'status' => $this->ggr ? trans('common.status.a') : trans('common.status.p')
                ]
                , 'hb' => [
                    'text' => trans('common.api.hb')
                    , 'ready' => 0
                    , 'status' => trans('common.status.p')
                ]
                , 'n11' => [
                    'text' => trans('common.api.n11')
                    , 'ready' => 0
                    , 'status' => trans('common.status.p')
                ]
            ]);
}
}
```

if i go to any route i got error because of apis variable undefined. i want use this variable everywhere

Comment: How do you log you user in?

Comment: normal user log in

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28970105/login-event-handling-in-laravel-5

Comment: @MartinHenriksen i don't want to log in . did u read question ?

Comment: "and i want that when the user logged in system this class should run auto and return true or false. i don't want to call this to every class." The linked question hooks into the event and will let you be able to run your code as you suggested to only be run once.

Comment: For this you have to create `middleware` and define this `middleware` in `kernal.php`  `$middleware` section

Comment: @Hannik Under `handle` method in middleware you can make your condition. I think this will help you.

Comment: what is `$ret`. I am not understand what do you want to say?