# Laravel: SetLocale based on value in users table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

#### Version:

- Laravel Version: 5.4.*
- PHP Version: 5.6.x

#### Description:

I have a locale variable stored in the `users` table. Now I want to change the language of the app based on the user's locale variable (when the user logs in).

#### Steps To Reproduce:

I created a new `middleware` file

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    App::setLocale(Session::has('lang') ? Session::get('lang') : Config::get('app.locale'));

    return $next($request);
}
```

And called this file in the `Kernel.php`

In my `LoginController` I have:

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    Session::put('lang', $user->lang);    
}
```

But this does not work. No errors, no different language. Anyone can help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it using a Event listener. With some help of this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44174931/event-listener-in-laravel-5-4) I managed to set the session variable based on the user's property. If someone needs more help, let me know!

Answer (score 0):

For me, I use this one it work fine for me.

```
Session::put('lang', Auth::user()->lang);
```

or with full path

```
Session::put('lang', \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::user()->lang);
```

Comment: Hi Kakada, just tried your 2 suggestions. I get this error: Trying to get property of non-object. dd(Auth::user()); is null ...

Comment: Ohh your user has lang property or not?
and you can debug with this dd(Auth::user()) and find the lang property, it has or not.

Comment: in my `middleware`, `dd(Auth::user());` returns always `null`, even if I am logged in

Comment: where did you put your code? In which file and function?